# How do I select a true/false expression in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, ssms

I am trying to select a boolean expression.

This does not work:

```
select *,
    (Column = 'x') as isX
from MyTable;

-- Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

But this does:

```
select *,
    IIF(Column = 'x', 1, 0) as isX
from MyTable;
```

I thought the first solution should have worked.

Is there a more elegant solution than using `IIF`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, for a few potential reasons:

- `=` is also used to assign a value to a variable, and thus the syntax would be ambiguous in some cases:

  ```
  DECLARE @var INT

  SELECT @var = 0   -- do you mean "set @var to 0" or "select true if @var IS 0"?
  ```
- there's not a native boolean type in SQL - `BIT` is the closest analog.

Another (more standard) option is CASE:

```
select *,
    CASE WHEN Column = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isX
from MyTable;
```